# Green screening in Compositor

Tags: node-editor, edit-mode, transparency, video

I am trying to remove the the green background from a video clip and every clip that I remove the green from makes part of the non-green object see-through. Anybody have a easy solution to fix this? Thanks Frank

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or video to help us out? It's not clear what's going on.

Comment: There is a Chrome Key node. Try to use it if you are not already doing it.